# Generating different density probabilities in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability-density, probability-theory

When using a something like `sample(c(rep(0, 5), 1), 6)` I am able generate a matrix like:

> `item A   B   C   D   E   F
>   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
>   2   0   1   0   0   0   0
>   3   1   0   0   0   0   0
>   4   0   0   0   0   1   0
>   5   0   0   0   0   1   0
>   6   0   0   1   0   0   0
>   7   0   0   0   1   0   0
>   8   0   1   0   0   0   0
>   9   1   0   0   0   0   0
>   10  0   0   0   0   1   0`

By design, if I generate a large  number of items (rows), the probability density of the traits (columns) will very similar, aka follow a Beta distribution (1,1):

[image]

How can I rewrite my R code, so that I am able to generate matrices where these 6 traits follow different beta distribution e.g: Beta (3,3)] or Beta (7,3)

[image] [image]

Comment: Have you seen the `rbeta` function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/Beta

Comment: Beta distributions are continuous while you want to generate a binary matrix? Why don't you directly generate a Beta distribution per column ?

Comment: Where did you get these pictures? These are discrete distributions, hence not Beta distributions.

Comment: Don't you mean a *Beta-binomial* distribution ?

Comment: Indeed, I 'm looking for a way to generate matrices, whose probability density  broadly follow beta distributions (for x=0; x=0.2, x=0.4, x=0.6, x=0.8 and x=1).

Answer (score 0):

Your distributions are not Beta distributions. You need something like that, with the probabilities you want (not clear) in the `probs` vector:

```
nsims <- 10000
sims <- matrix(0, nrow=nsims, ncol=6)
colnames(sims) <- LETTERS[1:6]
probs <- c(1/12, 1/6, 1/4, 1/4, 1/6, 1/12) # "Beta(3,3)" ??????
for(i in 1:nsims){
  sims[i,sample.int(6, 1, prob=probs)] <- 1 
}

barplot(colSums(sims)/nsims)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is very close to what I want to do.
I would like to generate 0/1 matrices that produce discrete distributions, that follow the broad patterns of beta like distributions 
(for x=0; x=0.2, x=0.4, x=0.6, x=0.8 and x=1)

Comment: take `probs <- diff(c(0, pbeta(c(1/6, 2/6, 3/6, 4/6, 5/6), 3, 3), 1))`

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly it.
Once beta can not be bimodal, except for (0.5,0.5), how can I generate a bimodal distribution?

Comment: again, you just have to define the probabilities you want in `probs`